# Message: Undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Me sale el siguiente mensaje de error y no he logrado solucionarlo.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: students

Filename: views/vEstudiante.php

Line Number: 85

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\stu\application\views\vEstudiante.php
Line: 85
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\stu\application\controllers\cEstudiante.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\stu\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Tengo lo siguiente en el controlador

```
   class cEstudiante extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()
   {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('mEstudiante'); //esta es la linea 19 del error

   }


    public function index(){


    $this->load->view('vEstudiante');


    $data['students'] = $this->mEstudiante->getAll();
    $this->load->view('vEstudiante',$data);

   }

   public function import()
   {
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        show_404();
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="text-danger">', '</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('file','File','callback_notEmpty');

    $response= false;
    if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
        $response['status']    = 'form-incomplete';
        $response['errors']    =    array(
            array(
                'field'    => 'input[name="file"]',
                'error'    => form_error('file')
            )
        );
    }
    else{
        try{

            $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)
            {
                $file = fopen($filename,"r");
                $is_header_removed = FALSE;
                while(($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {
                    if(!$is_header_removed){
                        $is_header_removed = TRUE;
                        continue;
                    }
                    $row = array(

                        'nombre_es'    =>  !empty($importdata[0])?$importdata[0]:'',
                        'apellido_pa'     =>  !empty($importdata[1])?$importdata[1]:'',
                        'apellido_ma'         =>  !empty($importdata[2])?$importdata[2]:''

                    );
                    $this->db->trans_begin();
                    $this->students_tbl_model->add($row);
                    if(!$this->db->trans_status()){
                        $this->db->trans_rollback();
                        $response['status']='error';
                        $response['message']='Something went wrong while saving your data';
                        break;
                    }else{
                        $this->db->trans_commit();
                        $response['status']='success';
                        $response['message']='Successfully added new record.';
                    }
                }
                fclose($file);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            $response['status']='error';
            $response['message']='Something went wrong while trying to communicate with the server.';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
public function notEmpty(){
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('notEmpty','The {field} field can not be empty.');
        return FALSE;
    }
 }

 }

 ?>
```

En la vista el error que me marca es el del foreach

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table class="table table-striped col-sm-12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td>Apellido Pat.</td>
                        <td>Apellido Mat.</td>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach((array)$students as $student): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $student['nombre_es']?></td>
                            <td><?= $student['apellido_pa']?></td>
                            <td><?= $student['apellido_ma']?></td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás cargando la vista doble vez

```
$this->load->view('vEstudiante');


$data['students'] = $this->mEstudiante->getAll();
$this->load->view('vEstudiante',$data);
```

una sin $data por lo cual la variable no existe;

Comment: Gracias, no , lo había notado :D